# How to target div at the end of the row?

Tags: javascript, html, targeting

I am trying to insert a box strip in between rows of divs, how can I target the end of each row's div?

Here's a JSFiddle of the divs: http://jsfiddle.net/5Sn94

Here's the code:

```
<div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
<div>
    <img src="//placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
<div>
   <img src="//placehold.it/50x50">
</div>
```

After a while, the divs will go onto the next line, creating a new 'row'. How can I insert a div which spans across the full page width, underneath a row of divs.

To show you what I want to achieve, visit this link on Google: http://bit.ly/1329rDn

And then you'll see if you click any image, it will open that new image bigger inbetween the div rows, how was this achieved? And how can I do the same?

Comment: did you use clear property ?

Comment: You are going to need to calculate the width of the divs, and when their accumulated width is greater than the container, you've started a new row, so you can insert the "display" after the last in that "row". This will need to be recalculated when the window resizes.

Comment: @thesystem Yep that's what I'd like to do (sounds spot on). Any ideas on how to even attempt it?

Comment: You could add a span after *every* div. Then use jQuery to filter those spans occur at offset 0, then apply your goodies to that. This has the advantage that it is responsive. You can run an update on('resize'...

Comment: @Halcyon21: I'd really suggest trying to do it on your own. Take it a step at a time, and when you get stuck on something specific that you just can't figure out, ask about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this can help you in your investigations:

```
div {
    display: inline-block; // <-- use display: inline-block instead of float: left
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.expander {
    background: coral;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    float: left; // <-- this float makes the trick
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5Sn94/14/

`.expander` is a div which needs to be inserted after target (hovered in my example) element. It has 100% width to occupy whole horizontal space.

To insert `expander` after hovered div I used this javascript (inside `for` loop):

```
div[i].onmouseover = function() {
    d.innerHTML = 'Details about div #' + this.dataset.id;
    this.parentNode.insertBefore(d, this.nextSibling).style.display = 'block';
}
```

You can insertAfter in jQuery, etc.

Comment: That works really well! One question though (and I am using jQuery so feel free to use)... Let's say 'expander' is already created, but set to display none, and on click, I want to show the expander, using 'fadeIn' method. How would you convert your function to move it on a click function and not a hover?

Comment: Love this, perfect. A good learning experience for me too, and a great use of CSS. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByTagName` but it will only work if you don't have any other divs on the page http://jsfiddle.net/5Sn94/2/

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
divs[divs.length-1].style.border = '1px solid red';
```

Comment: Thanks jcubic, but what I want to achieve is targeting the div at the end of the _row_ and not the entire list of divs. So if there are 5 rows of divs, the end div of each line, will be highlighted red.

Comment: With what? The HTML doesn't need to be updated to achieve what I'm looking for, Google have done it using rows of divs.

Comment: @Halcyon21 sorry misunderstood your question.

Answer (score -1):

Using jQuery, you can use the `last-child` selector: http://jsfiddle.net/5Sn94/1/

Comment: This targets the very last div, I want to do that, but on every row, so the div nearest the right hand side of the webpage, is highlighted red too.

Comment: I can change this so that it doesn't use jQuery, if you want, haha.

Comment: No jQuery is absolutely fine, what I am trying to do is pretty complex and not worth the browser patching. Thanks Matt for this.